# All products being displayed instead of only one

Tags: php, mysql

i edited my code as below but the issue is that each time i click on the edit link, all of the products are being displayed instead of only the one beside which i clicked the edit link.

note: Sorry for posting another question relating to my other one. I could not add any more comments.

```
<?php
include_once("db_connect.php");

if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
$prod_id = $_POST['prod_id'];

$prod_name=$_POST['prod_name'];
$prod_brand=$_POST['prod_brand'];
$prod_price=$_POST['prod_price'];   

// checking empty field
if(empty($prod_price))
{
    //if name field is empty
    if(empty($prod_price))
    {
        echo "<font color='red'>Price field is empty.</font><br/>";
    }

}   
else
{   
    //updating the table
    //$result=mysql_query("UPDATE tblretprod SET prod_price='$prod_price' WHERE prod_id=$prod_id");
    $result=mysql_query("UPDATE tblretprod SET prod_price='".$prod_price."' WHERE prod_id='".$prod_id."';");

    //redirectig to the display page. In our case, it is index.php
    header("Location: update.php");
}
}
?>
<?php

$prod_id = $_GET['prod_id'];

$result=mysql_query("SELECT a.prod_name, a.prod_brand, b.prod_price FROM tblproduct a, tblretprod b where a.prod_id = b.prod_id") or die(mysql_error());

?>
<html>
<title>Edit Product</title>
<body>
<a href="#">Home</a>
<br/><br/>
<form name="edit" method="post" action="updprod.php">
<table border="0">
<?php
while($res=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$prod_name = $res['prod_name'];
$prod_brand = $res['prod_brand'];
$prod_price = $res['prod_price'];

?>
<tr> 
<td>Product Name</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="prod_name" value = "<?php echo $prod_name;?>">   </td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>Brand</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="prod_brand" value = "<?php echo $prod_brand;?>">           </td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>Product Price</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="prod_price" value = "<?php echo $prod_price;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="prod_id" value = "<?php echo $_GET['prod_id'];?>">
</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?> 
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"></td>
</tr>
</table> 
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so can post your edit link example  ?

Comment: Remember to sanitaze all user input from your $_GET requests ( using mysqli_real_escape_string, htmlspecialchars..) and use PDO/mysqli for interact your DB. Never trust users!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add in your select query in `WHERE` clause:

```
AND a.prod_id = ".$prod_id."
```

query:

```
"SELECT 
    a.prod_name, 
    a.prod_brand, 
    b.prod_price 
FROM 
    tblproduct a, tblretprod b 
where 
    a.prod_id = b.prod_id
    AND a.prod_id = ".intval($prod_id).""
```

To make the query safer against SQL Injection i've added `intval` function like *Kickstart* well pointed out.

Comment: Thank you...very much. It solves the issue. How i close questions i opened please?

Comment: @user2534128 glad i could help :) you need to accept an answer

Comment: This will do it, but further to earlier comments ensure that $prod_id is a safe value.  If it is an id field then I would assume it is an integer, in which case just using intval($prod_id) when adding it to the select is probably the simplest safe method.

Comment: @Kickstart you have a valid point there , ill update the answer